# Centered wrapper in full width divs

Tags: css, html

I found this thread on here which answers my question. I want to ask a question relating to this thread, but I'm not sure how to comment on the thread...excuse my ignorance :)

I followed the instructions of the ticked answer and it worked. Then in my content div I want three divs, but when I float one left...my background-color ont he content div won't stretch. So it looks something like:

html:

```
<div id="content">

   <div class="wrapper">

<div id="content1></div>
<div id="content2></div>
<div id="content3></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content 1 {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
#content 2 {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
#content 3 {
    width:300px;
    float:right;
}
```

I will probably have to link you guys to the site before youc an understand what I'm waffling about. But it's not online yet so I just thought someone might be aware of an issue with floating divs left or right when using this wrapper class technique?

Colm

Comment: Could you show the HTML part of your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask only because you didn't mention it, but did you clear your floats after the floating divs? Make sure you do like this:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

or you could put:

```
overflow: hidden; width: 100%;
```

in the style attribute of your wrapping div.

Try these options and see if they work for you.

Comment: I didn't clear the floats, but I tried height:auto and height:overflow on the content div which the three floated divs are in....

Comment: So where do I put the overflow: hidden; width: 100%? On which div?

Comment: On the div that wraps the three inner divs.